# How can I debug the object type returned to the subscriber of an Angular observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular-httpclient, rxjs6

I'm a newbie to **Angular-7**, **RxJS-6** and **Visual Studio Code** and I'm having difficulty debugging an Observable that is being returned to a subscriber with the result that I have a runtime "TypeError" being raised by the subscriber. From research, it would appear that I'm not alone with tricky problems like this. Can you either suggest how I can determine what the subscriber is "observing" or can you spot the error in my code below?

**In Detail**

I'm writing a very simple proof of concept using Visual Studio Code and the Angular-7 CLI to retrieve the current system date/time from a server using angular's `httpclient` and display it.

Refer to the method *instrument.service.ts::getSystemTimeDate()* below. The HTTP layer is fine in that the JSON response is obtained ...

```
{
  "SystemDateTime": "2018-11-26T08:54:06.894Z"
}
```

Within the `map` operator, this response is first converted to an object of type `SystemDateTimeResponse` and then to a `Date` and the method should return an `Observable<Date>` to any subscribers. What I am having trouble with is the component's subscription to `Observable<Date>`. At runtime, this subscriber in the method `onTimeDateBtnClick()` throws an error:

```
ERROR
TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
message: "You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable."
stack: "TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    at subscribeTo (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:75870:15)
    at subscribeToResult (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:76027:76)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:70784:90)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:70778:14)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:70761:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:65218:18)
    at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:73228:26)
    at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:65218:18)
    at TakeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/take.js.TakeSubscriber._next (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:72950:30)
    at TakeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:65218:18)"
__proto__: Error {constructor: , name: "TypeError", message: "", …}
constructor: function TypeError() { … }
message: ""
name: "TypeError"
toString: function toString() { … }
__proto__: Object {constructor: , name: "Error", message: "", …}
```

I believe that I am not properly returning an *Observable* and may be screwing up my use of the map operator. What am I missing?

---

**The Code**

The software references of this snippet include:

**timedate.component.html**: contains the simple template of

```
<p>
  Last time I checked, it was : {{today | date:'medium'}}
</p>
<button mat-button (click)="onTimedateBtnClick()">Update</button>
```

**timedate.component.ts**: contains the display property definition of `today` and the event handler `onTimedateBtnClick()` which uses a data service to manage the HTTP request/response, retrieving the current date/time from a server.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { InstrumentService } from '../instrument.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-timedate',
  templateUrl: './timedate.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./timedate.component.css']
})
export class TimedateComponent implements OnInit {

  /** Display property */
  today: Date;

  /**
   * Constructor
   * @param - data service
   */
  constructor(private dataService: InstrumentService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.today = new Date();  /// initialise with client's date/time
  }

  /**
   *  User event handler requesting system time/date from the server
   */
  onTimedateBtnClick() {
    const http$: Observable<Date> = this.dataService.getSystemTimeDate();

    http$.subscribe(
      res => this.today = res,
    );
  }
}
```

**instrument.service.ts**: contains the `getSystemTimeDate()` method which returns an `Observable<Date>`. Again, I've simplified the code (although it still fails) and exaggerated the *map* in order to better see what I'm doing.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

// App imports
import { SystemDateTimeResponse, SystemDateTimeUrl } from './instrument.service.httpdtos';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
 })
export class InstrumentService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  /**
   * Return the server date and time
   */
  public getSystemTimeDate(): Observable<Date> {
    // Convert the server response object into an observable date
    const responseObject: Observable<Date> =
    this.http.get<SystemDateTimeResponse>(SystemDateTimeUrl.Url).
      pipe(
        map(jsonResponse => {
          const newDto = new SystemDateTimeResponse(jsonResponse.SystemDateTime);
          const d = new Date(newDto.SystemDateTime);
          return d;
        }),
      );

    return responseObject;
  }
}
```

**instrument.service.httpdtos.ts** : Contains data transfer object definitions.

```
/** URL - Instrument system date/time */
export class SystemDateTimeUrl {
  public static readonly HttpVerb = 'GET';
  public static readonly Url = 'api/instrument/systemdatetime';
  public static readonly Summary = 'Query the instrument current date/time';
}

/** Response DTO */
export class SystemDateTimeResponse {
  constructor(
    public SystemDateTime: string     // In UTC format
  ) { }
}
```

Comment: http$.subscribe(
      res => {
  //Do debug here
  this.today = res;
   }
    );

Comment: Post the exact and complete error you're gettign. tell us whichline(s) it refers to.

Comment: @Vijay, many thanks, but unfortunately the error occurs within the Angular libraries before the subscriber anonymous function is called.

Comment: @JB, many thanks - you are correct. I have added some clarification in the post showing that the error is raised by the Angular libraries. I suppose I could go deep and set breakpoints there.

Comment: @billmcf123 have you check that error in chrome debugger? or have you identified that error? Please paste here error log.

Comment: @Vijay I was eventually able to learn how to debug the problem using chrome and found myself deep in the rxjs observable library. I was able to see that the observable I thought was being returned from `this.http.get<SystemDateTimeResponse>(...)` was in fact junk. It would appear that what I thought was a correct **get** response was only a sub component of the entire http response. As it tuned out, all of the code I pasted above was correct. many thanks for your help again.

Comment: @billmcf123 Then please vote up my comment.

Comment: @Vijay I wish I could. My reputation is still too small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options. If you are using Chrome for developing this application, you could go in developer tools, find your source code in webpack, and within the service you could add multiple breakpoints for debugging purposes. The tricky part is to find the sources. From there it should be strait forward.  [image]

The second option, if you use Intellij IDEA / WebStorm, you could debug the app in your editor. To do that, you must install [JetBrains IDE Support](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jetbrains-ide-support/hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji) extension in Chrome / Firefox and after that you must configure your editor to add a new Configuration : Editor Configuration -> Javascript Debugger. You must specify the correct port (if your app runs on a different port) [image]
Once you've started both the app and the debugging configuration, add a new breakpoint within your code (callback on your subscription / map function) and you should be able to inspect what variables you have.

If you have any other questions, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Many thanks. Using the Chrome debugger helped me to get to the bottom of the problem (described above).